# How to get price of related product when I select product from a selectbox?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, jquery-selectbox

How to get the price of the related product, when I select the product from selectbox?

I am fetching product names and prices from database (Laravel Mysql project).
I want to display price on price text box.
Following is my view`

```
<form role="form">                    
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="Vehicle"> Vehicle Name:</label>
    <select class="form-control">
    @foreach($servicevehicles as $servicevehicle )
        <option>{{$servicevehicle->vehiclename}}</option>


<!--here dispaly vehicle name-->
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="price"> Price</label>
<!--i want to display related product when i select related vehicle from above selectbox-->
    <input type="text" class="form-control" >
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Where you want to get the _price_?

Comment: to price text box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to print the price as data-attribute in the option tag like this:

```js
$('.vehicle-type').on('change', function() {
  $('.price-input')
  .val(
    $(this).find(':selected').data('price')
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form role="form">                    
<div class="form-group vehicle-type">
    <label for="Vehicle"> Vehicle Name:</label>
    <select class="form-control">
        <option data-price="345">Title 1</option>
        <option data-price="122">Title 2</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="price"> Price</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control price-input" readonly>
</div>
</form>
```

Then with JS (jQuery) listen to the Change event to extract new value from the selected option.
This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this

```
$("#your_option").change(function() {
     var get_text = $("#your_option option:selected").text();
    //Do something with the get_text
});
```

This will get the text of the option thats selected fiddle about with it and apply it for your code

Answer (score 0):

use foreach like this:

```
@foreach($servicevehicles as $key => $value)
<option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $value }}</option>
@endforeach
```

In your controller define the servicevehicles

```
$servicevehicles = Model::all()->pluck('name','price');
```

And use this script.

```html
<form>
<select id="selectid00">
  <option value="samsung">Samsung</option>
  <option value="iphone">Iphone</option>
  <option value="generalmobile">GM</option>
  <option value="sony">Sony</option>
</select>
</form>
<button type="button" onclick="f01()">f01</button>
<p id="p00">TEXT</p>


<script>
function f01() {
    var x = document.getElementById("selectid00").value;
    document.getElementById("p00").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple code:

```js
$('#select_car').on('change', function() {
  $('.input_price').val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form role="form">                    
<div class="form-group ">
    <label for="Vehicle"> Vehicle Name:</label>
    <select id="select_car" class="form-control">
        <option value="10000">Honda</option>
        <option value="2000">Toyota</option>
        <option value="100000">Ford</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="price"> Price</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control input_price" readonly>
</div>
</form>
```