# Selected product name to auto populate price from DB

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-4, laravel-5.8

I have tried the solution given at [How to get price of related product when I select product from a selectbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48437891/how-to-get-price-of-related-product-when-i-select-product-from-a-selectbox)  but still I can't solve my issue.
This is my form (laravel blade):

```php
    @extends('layouts.app')

    @section('content')
        <br>
        <h1>Add Sale</h1>
        {!! Form::open(['action' => 'SalesController@store', 'method' => 'POST', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) !!}

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="product_name">Product Name</label>
            <select name="product_name" id="product_name" class="form-control">
                <option>Select Product Name</option>
                @foreach ($stocks as $stock)
                    <option value="{{ $stock->stock_name }}">{{ $stock->stock_name}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {{Form::label('sale_quantity', 'Quantity')}}
            {{Form::text('sale_quantity', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Quantity'])}}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="unit_selling_price">Unit Selling Price </label>
            <select name="unit_selling_price" id="unit_selling_price" class="form-control">
                <option>Select Unit Selling Price</option>
                @foreach ($stocks as $stock)
                    <option value="{{ $stock->unit_selling_price }}">{{ $stock->unit_selling_price}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {{Form::label('total_sales_cost', 'Total Sales Cost')}}
            {{Form::text('total_sales_cost', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Total Sales Cost'])}}
        </div>
        {{Form::submit('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])}}
        {!! Form::close() !!}
    @endsection
```

Form Screenshot above.
[image]

Comment: You'll need javascript to update the Unit Selling Price drop down when you change the Product dropdown. You can either load all of the products/prices into a json when you load the page, or get the prices via Ajax.

Comment: Can you show me the Ajax way or link me to a resource. I'll really appreciate.

Comment: Hello @Mateus Juunges help me over here

Comment: Clarifying, you want to update the `total sales cost` field based on the product multiplying by it's unit selling price?

Comment: No, it's the unit_selling_price I want to update based on the chosen product name. Look form picture. @Mateus Junges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### SalesController.php changes

```
public function getUnitSellingPrice(Request $request, $stock_id)
{

    $stock = Stock::where('stock_id', $stock_id)->first();
    if ($stock == null) {
        return null;
    }

    return response()->json($stock->unit_selling_price);
}
```

#### create.blade.php changes

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Product Name</label>
    <select name="product_name" class="form-control" id="stock_name">
        <option>Select Product Name</option>
        @foreach ($stocks as $stock)
            <option value="{{ $stock->stock_id }}">{{ $stock->stock_name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('unit_selling_price', 'Unit Selling Price')}}
    {{Form::text('unit_selling_price', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Unit Selling Price', 'id' => 'unit_selling_price'])}}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('sale_quantity', 'Quantity')}}
    {{Form::text('sale_quantity', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Quantity', 'id' => 'sales_quantity'])}}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('total_sales_cost', 'Total Sales Cost')}}
    {{Form::text('total_sales_cost', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Total Sales Cost', 'id' => 'total_sales_cost', 'readonly' => 'true', 'cursor: pointer' => 'true' ])}}
</div>



{{Form::submit('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])}}
{!! Form::close() !!}

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#stock_name").on('change', function () {
            var stock_id = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '/sales-price/getunitsellingprice/'+stock_id,
                method: 'GET',
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    $("#unit_selling_price").val(response);
                },
            });
        });
    });
</script>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#total_sales_cost").click(function () {
            var sales_quantity = $("#sales_quantity").val();

            var unit_selling_price = $("#unit_selling_price").val();
            var total_sales_cost = (sales_quantity * unit_selling_price);

            $('#total_sales_cost').val(total_sales_cost);
        });
    });
</script>
```

#### Route changes

```
Route::any('sales-price/getunitsellingprice/{stock_id}','SalesController@getUnitSellingPrice');
```

Comment: @Mateus Junges Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use ajax. You can pass the `stock_name` as a route parameter or with the ajax data attribute. For this example, i'll use the data attribute.

```js
$("#product_name").on('change', function() {
    let element = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'your-url-here',
        method: 'GET',
        data: {
            'stock_name': element.val(),
        },
        success: function(response) {
            $("#unit_selling_price").val(response.data).trigger('change');
        },
    });
});
```

Your PHP script, in some controller method will look like this one:

```php
public function getTotalCost(Request $request)
{
    $stock = Stock::where('stock_name', 'like', $request->input("stock_name"))->first();
    if ($stock == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return response()->json($stock->unit_selling_price);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry about my late reply, I was at University for a test. You want to select the unit cost and fill the second select, correct?

Comment: No, that is not. The `=` should be `:`.

Comment: Look at this for the last time please, so we can be done with this issue. The Unit Selling Price is not coming automatically in the form still. (I hope u understand its the Unit Selling Price of the specific stock/product name chosen that should appear when a stock/product name is chosen in the form. 
blade: https://slack-files.com/TP02E38GN-FNZMS5EKH-918fc1dd44
Controller: https://slack-files.com/TP02E38GN-FNRDCCF9P-988d57ff45 @Mateus Junges

Comment: if you add a `console.log(response.data)` in your js, what is shown in the browser console?

Comment: I have added that then once I select a stock/product_name this is shown in the console:
ReferenceError: response is not defined
<anonymous> 
dispatch 
add/elemData.handle

https://slack-files.com/TP02E38GN-FNXP30RNG-c08893b449

@Mateus Junges 
Thanks

Comment: You need to add it within the `success` callback function. There is no way to have response as undefined.

Comment: in console I see in red:
GET XHR localhost:8000/sales/@Url.Action(%22getUnitSellingPrice%22,%22SalesController%22) [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 379ms]

@Mateus Junges

Comment: I have this as my URL in ajax JScript:
url: '@Url.Action("getUnitSellingPrice","SalesController")',

Comment: I think the JScript ajax is good, the controller function might be the issue. See my DB pic here: 
https://files.slack.com/files-pri/TP02E38GN-FNKF257K4/image.png?pub_secret=9eb5dd23ec

Comment: No, i think your controller is ok. Change the `url` to the route u want to use, like `/getUnitSellingPrice`. The @url will not work.

Comment: so the url is wtitten in the blade here:
C:\Apache24\htdocs\printshopsales\resources\views\sales\create.blade.php



.And directed  to the getUnitSellingPrice controller function which is here:
C:\Apache24\htdocs\printshopsales\app\Http\Controllers\SalesController.php

Comment: I have added this in web.php:
Route::any('sales/getunitsellingprice','SalesController@getUnitSellingPrice');

The script URL is still:   url: '/sales/getunitsellingprice',    Then I get this still: GET XHR localhost:8000/sales/getUnitSellingPrice [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 229ms] @Mateus Junges

Comment: @aynber take a look to my above comment.